# Empty rows are getting appended to JQGrid on calling addRowData

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jqgrid

I am having JQgrid this way,

**HTML:**

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<input type="button" id="UpdateGridButton" value="Update" />
```

And I am initally loading JSon string namely 'mydata ' to JQgrid this way,

**JavaScript:**

```
var mydata = [{id: 48803, thingy: "DSK1"}, {id:48769, thingy:"APPR"}, {id:12313, thingy: 'FOOBAR'}];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
        datastr : mydata,
        datatype : 'jsonstring',
    gridview: true,
    height : '100%',
        autowidth : true,
    height: 'auto',
    autoencode: true,
    rowNum: mydata.length,
    rownumbers : true,
        rownumWidth : 40,
        multiselect : false,
        viewrecords : true,
        autoencode : true,
        scrollrows : true,
        hoverrows:true,
        width: '100%',
        shrinkToFit: false,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
    },{
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
    }],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example"
});
```

And it is working.

Issue is when i try to append some more rows to the existing JQrid this way,

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#UpdateGridButton').click(function(){
newData = [[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"]];
    var p = $('#grid').getGridParam();
    alert("found gridParamData:", p.data);
    if (p.data){        
        var rowId = $.jgrid.randId();
        $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', rowId, newData);
        console.log(rowId);

        /*for (var i = 0; i <= newData.length; i++) {
       jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, newData[i]);
}*/
    }
    /*for (var i = 0; i <= newData.length; i++) {
       jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, newData[i]);
}*/
});
```

Rows are getting appended but the they are empty.

My data is in the form of array like this,

```
newData = [[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"],[462,"abc"]];
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newData` is not valid json and needs to be a key/value pair, so your new data isn't correct, change your `newData` array to the following:

```
[{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"},{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"},{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"},{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"},{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"},{"id" : 462, "thingy":"abc"}];
```

Then `addRowData` and you will see it works fine.

See [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/5zq5530h/)